# Forum migration without ID matches: how to handle 301 redirect?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, seo

I'm migrating a custom php forum to the new Discourse forum.

My custom php forum has an url like this:

http://www.dday.it/?a=forum&p=topic&oid=18983&threaded

The new forum has an url like this:

http://meta.discourse.org/t/permission-inconsistency-and-others/11573

The easy way of course is with .htaccess 301 redirect, but I have a problem: when I migrate my data from mysql to pg I lose the ID match, so the ID of my topics in the old forum doesn't match the ID of the same topic on the new forum.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if 301 redirects is the "easy" way. Your going to essentially enumerate every thread ID and map it to its new ID as well as the thread title. If you've got 20,000 threads, you'll have 20,000 individual:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)a=forum($|&)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)p=topic($|&)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)oid=18983($|&)
RewriteRule ^$ http://meta.discourse.org/t/permission-inconsistency-and-others/11573 [L,R=301]
```

The other way to go about it is to pipe all requests to some script on your old forum's site, for example:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /redirect.php [L,QSA]
```

That script will need to be able to read the oid's (e.g. `$_GET['oid']`), maybe look in the old database for a thread title, then look in the new database for that thread title, then fetch the new thread ID, and then redirect the browser to the new URL.